# Either who or whom?

Tags: construction

In present day English, I think both of the followings are correct

> The specialist who you want to meet is available only on weekends.
>
> The specialist whom you want to meet is available only on weekends.

Am I right? Do they make any difference in meaning?

Comment: Yes. Both are correct. There is a difference is style. The former is neutral but the latter would be used in a formal context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. There is a difference is style. The former is neutral but the latter would be used in a formal context.